# AttributeError in String Formatting Function

Tags: python

I've encountered an AttributeError while working with the following code snippet. I'd appreciate any help with this issue.

```py
def lyrics(animal, sound):
    print('''Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!
And on that farm he had a {1}, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!
With a {2}, {2} here and a {2}, {2} there.
Here a {2}, there a {2}, everywhere a {2}, {2}.
Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!''').format(animal, sound)
```

The error message received is as follows:

```
File "c6e1.py", line 19, in main
    lyrics("buffalo", "boo")
  File "c6e1.py", line 16, in lyrics
    Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!''').format(animal, sound)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'format'
```

Any insights and suggestions are welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: The `format()` call needs to go directly after the string, _inside_ the `print()` parentheses

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
def lyrics(animal, sound):

    print('''Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!
And on that farm he had a {0}, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!
With a {1}, {1} here and a {1}, {1} there.
Here a {1}, there a {1}, everywhere a {1}, {1}.
Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!'''.format(animal, sound))
```

`print("""any_string""")` would return `NoneType` and you can't do string formatting on it. You need to do `print("""any_string""".fomrat(formatters))`.

**NOTE**: Using positional arguments in `.format()` like in your function above should produce another error as it's indexing starts from `0`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you call the format function on the return value of print(), which is None. You have to call it on the string inside the parentheses.
Second, the indices of arguments of format() are zero-based, so you need to adjust them es well.

Answer (score 0):

From python 3.6 and further you could use `f-strings`

```
def lyrics(animal, sound):

    print(f'''Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!
And on that farm he had a {animal}, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!
With a {sound}, {sound} here and a {sound}, {sound} there.
Here a {sound}, there a {sound}, everywhere a {sound}, {sound}.
Old MacDonald had a farm, Ee-igh, Ee-igh, Oh!''')
```